# Sufficiently rigorous limit proof?

Tags: limits

I needed to make the substitution $x = \sqrt{t^2+1} - t$ in an integral where in one limit $t\to+\infty$. So $x\to 0$ at this limit. I am aware you could complete the square under radical with an expression greater than  $\sqrt{t^2+1} - t$, and then use the fact that this greater expression tends to zero.
But my question is, is it simply not rigorous enough to say that as $t\to+\infty$., $t^2+1\to t^2$ so that $\sqrt{t^2+1}\to t$ and so $x\to 0$ ?

Sorry it took me a while to get to the actual question! Many thanks!

Comment: Note that $lim_{t \to \infty} t^2+1-t^2 = 1$, therefore $t^2+1 \to t$ as $t \to \infty$ is not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not rigourous, and it can lead to false limis.

(Counter-)example:

You could use the same argument to saythat, as $\,t^2+t\to t^2$ as $t\to\infty$, $\sqrt{t^2+t}-t\to 0$.

Unfortunately, using the conjugate expressions, you'll find the limit is $\dfrac12$.

*First method: conjugate expression:*
$$\sqrt{t^2+t}-t=\frac{(\sqrt{t^2+t})^2-t^2}{\sqrt{t^2+t}+t}=\frac t{\sqrt{t^2+t}+t}=\frac 1{\sqrt{1+\dfrac1t}+1}$$
(I supposed $t>0$)

*Send method: binomial formula*
$$\sqrt{t^2+t}=t\sqrt{1+\dfrac1t}=t\Bigl(1+\dfrac1{2t}+o\Bigl(\dfrac1t\Bigr)\Bigr)=t+\dfrac12+o(1)$$
hence $$\sqrt{t^2+t}-t=\dfrac12+o(1)$$

Comment: I see. Sorry I know this wasn't in the original question, but how could one go about evaluating that limit?

Comment: Do you mean the counter-example in my post?

Comment: Yeah, the sqrt(t^2+t) - t as t -> 1/2. I'm unsure what you meant by using the conjugate expressions?

Comment: I added  some details. Hope this is clear, albeit succinct.

Comment: I think you meant to write $(\sqrt{t^2+t})^2-t^2$ in the conjugate-expression method.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for pointing the typo.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $t=\sinh u$, as $u\to\infty$. Then use $\cosh u\pm\sinh u=e^{\large\pm u}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x = \sqrt{t^2+t} - t=t \sqrt{1+\frac 1 {t}}-t=t\Big(\sqrt{1+\frac 1 {t}}-1 \Big)$$ Now, remember that, for small $a$, $$\sqrt{1+a}=1+\frac{a}{2}-\frac{a^2}{8}+O\left(a^3\right)$$ Replace $a$ by $\frac 1{t}$ and get $$x=t\Big(1+\frac{1}{2 t}-\frac{1}{8 t^2}+\cdots-1)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8 t}+\cdots$$